# WebLogic 12c - Destination unreachable exception

Tags: java, java-7, java-6, weblogic12c

First, I had installed jdk 1.6.0_43 and oracle weblogic 12.1.1, I was successfully able to deploy my application.

I then upgraded both my jdk (1.7.0_60) and weblogic (12.1.2), but was unable to deploy my application.

Now, I downgraded my weblogic (12.1.1) but retained my jdk 1.7.0_60, but i was still not able to deploy my application successfully.

In both the failure cases, I got the same error with the following message. Is there something with respect to java 7 I should be aware of? I tried searching for this a lot, but in vain..

```
 [exec] javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3://localhost:9991: Destination unreachable; nested exception is: 
 [exec] java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; No available router to destination]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No available router to destination  -- Means you do not have a service running to listen on localhost:9991

Go to admin console, check the servers which should be listening on 9991 is up and running.
I am sure it is not running.

Comment: The server was running. And I'm sure that I've configured my ListenerAddress to be localhost and ListenPort to be 9991. I cross-checked my config.xml and they have the same values. Could there be any other reason behind this?

Comment: java.net.ConnectException: t3://localhost:9991: Destination unreachable  means that there is no was service running on localhost 9991, use west/wls console/netstat --listen to confirm that the service is actually running and listening to 9991. Hope you have the server running locally and not elsewhere on another machine

Answer (score 4):

[oracle's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20131215135921/https://blogs.oracle.com/wlscoherence/entry/java_net_socketexception_connection_reset) points that you have to enable tunneling:

> access the administration console, click servers-> server you want to
> reach-> protocols -> http -> enable Tunneling.

Answer (score 4):

a few possibilities

1. Not listening - check with netstat
2. No tunneling - check Summary of Servers -> Configure server (admin) -> Protocols tab -> HTTP sub tab-> Enable Tunneling
3. JDeveloper does not trust the SSL certificate - check root CA e.g.

   $ cd /oracle/Middleware-12.2.1.2/oracle_common

   $ jdk/bin/keytool -import -v -file ca.crt -storepass changeit -keystore jdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts -alias MyCA

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps (Must be done on *Admin* only):

1. Login to **Weblogic Console**
2. Click **Lock and Edit**
3. Go to **Servers**
4. Go to **Admin**
5. Go to **protocols**
6. Go to **HTTP**
7. Scroll down and click on **Enable Tunneling**
8. **Save**
9. **Activate** (No restart needed)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my Weblogic server while building with maven

If you're using maven, make sure in your maven `settings.xml` file, the value for: `<weblogic.admin.url></weblogic.admin.url>` is the same what you have for `listen-address></listen-address>` your weblogic `config.xml`

My problem was that my `settings.xml` had my local IP address where as weblogic `config.xml` had localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem in WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.3.0 and it was resolved by changing the SSL port. On the same server, Admin server and managed server had similar ports for the SSL even though both the ports were disabled yet there was conflict. After changing the ssl port number i was able to solve the problem.

1. Go to Weblogic Console
2. Click on the managed server
3. Under configuration -> General enable ssl and ensure the port mentioned is unique and is not being used by AdminServer or any of the managed servers.