# Configuring SSL in Weblogic

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, weblogic12c

I trying to configure SSL for my weblogic server 12.2.1. I created self-signed keystore and truststore SSL certificates using JDK keytool utility, configured it through the Admin console, set "SSL listen port enabled" to true and changed it to 8888. After all, I deployed my web service to the server. So, web service works on https with no problem. But when I want to restart weblogic, I get this error:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: t3s://localhost:8888: [RJVM:000575]Destination 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 8888 unreachable.; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; [RJVM:000576]No available router to destination.; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.ConnectException: [RJVM:000576]No available router to destination. [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: t3s://localhost:8888: [RJVM:000575]Destination 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 8888 unreachable.; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; [RJVM:000576]No available router to destination.; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.ConnectException: [RJVM:000576]No available router to destination.]

Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
File "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\shutdown-AdminServer.py", line 3, in ?
File "<iostream>", line 19, in connect
File "<iostream>", line 553, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error occurred while performing connect : Cannot connect via t3s or https. If using demo certs, verify that the -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust system property is set. : t3s://localhost:8888: [RJVM:000575]Destination 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 8888 unreachable.; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect; [RJVM:000576]No available router to destination.; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.ConnectException: [RJVM:000576]No available router to destination.
```

What is the reason for appearing this problem? How to fix it? I also checked config.xml and it contains actual information about port. For developing I use Eclipse Neon. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489922/weblogic-12c-destination-unreachable-exception

Comment: @devwebcl I have already seen this post and I tried to use solutions that described there but it doesn't help...Are there any other ways to resolve it?

Comment: Are you restarting the admin server or a manager server from the same domain ?

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin yes, I have only one domain and I restarting server using eclipse. Console prints error as above.

Comment: As far as I can tell, wlst does not trust the self signed certificate of the AdminServer, when executing the shutdown-AdminServer.py. I think that you need to import the self signed certificate to the default java's trust store (cacerts) using java keytool.

Comment: @komarios, but this error also occurs when I trying to use demo certificate.

Comment: If you are using Demo certs, the error clearly states that you need to use "-Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust" as a JAVA_OPTIONS startup parameter. Otherwise, you would need to import the demo certiifcate inside cacerts as well.

Comment: @komarios, so, where can I set JAVA_OPTIONS startup parameter?

Comment: Please see here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259452/how-do-i-pass-d-argument-in-eclipse-to-my-weblogic-server